# How to reduce/change a transformer output frequency and voltage (60Hz -50Hz and 3000V-400V)

Tags: power, transformer

I have two 1000kVA; 15000V/3000V @60Hz and one 1000kVA 15000V/3000V oil immersed old transformers.  I am going to use them for interconnecting my three pumping stations run from three phase 380V @50Hz (500kW PV+600kW diesel generators each) from different locations. I want to share only solar PV power (500kW) from any station to any station.

How could I change the frequency from 60Hz to 50Hz and voltage from 3000V to 380(400)V?

Can I reduce no secondary winding?

Comment: Transformers don't change frequency.

Comment: To put it bluntly, if you're asking this kind of question **here**, you have no idea what you're doing. You need to hire a professional consulting engineer to design this for you.

Answer (score 4):

Do not try to wire that system yourself.  The lack of knowledge as shown in the question and the voltage and power levels involved make it very likely you'll damage the equipment and injure (or kill) yourself (or someone else.)

1. Transformers don't change the line frequency.  The 60Hz or 50 Hz rating is what your are supposed to use it with, not what it will change it to.
2. A transformer made for 50 Hz will probably do OK when used on 60 Hz.
3. A transformer made for 60 Hz will probably overheat when used with 50 Hz.
4. A transformer has a turns ratio.  The voltage going in on the primary side will be multiplied by the turns ratio on the secondary side.
5. Your transformers have a turns ratio of 1 (secondary) to 5 (primary.)  The primary voltage will be divided by 5.  To get 380V out of the secondary, you would have to put 1900 V in on the primary.
6. To change the turns ratio you'd have to disassemble the transformers (draining and storing the oil first) then rewind either the primary or the secondary.  Rewinding the primary means replacing a whole lot of wire with far less (but thicker) wire.  Rewinding the secondary means replacing relatively little (but thick) wire with a lot more wire (but thinner.)

It is not clear why you need the transformers.  If the pumps are all relatively close together then you shouldn't need transformers - just connect them all to the PV system.

If the pumps are far enough apart that you need high voltage then you could run the 380 V from the PV system in the secondary of one transformer and get high voltage from the secondary.  You'd then run lines to the remote sites and use your remaining two transformers to lower the voltage back down to 380V.  That would only work if the PV system is at the same site as one of the pumps.  If you have to run high voltage to three remote sites then you'll need four transformers - one at the PV site to produce high voltage, and one at each of the remote sites to lower it back to 380V.

That ignores all of the things that go into making a safe installation - there are wiring and safety standards you'll have to follow.  There's probably also building permits and inspections to be taken care of, as well.

This is not a job to do based on advice from some people on the internet that you've never met.

This is a job for a licensed professional who can design the system and have it built, installed, and operated safely for you.